# SSRS Conditional Formatting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, conditional-formatting, ssrs-tablix

I am working on SSRS Ranking report, where Rank 1 should have background of Green and last Rank should have background of Red.

Example below:

[image: SSRS Conditional Formatting]

I tried using custom code but that's not working for me as below:

SSRS Expression used as below:

```
=Code.RankColour(me.value, 1, Fields!RankName.Value)
```

And RankColor code as below:

```
Public Function RankColourTotals(ByVal Value As Decimal, ByVal MinValue As Decimal, ByVal MaxValue As Decimal) As String
    Dim strColor As String

    Select Case Value
        Case MaxValue
            strColor = "Salmon"
        Case MinValue
            strColor = "LightGreen"
        Case Else
            strColor = "Gainsboro"
    End Select
    Return strColor
End Function
```

**Note**: I am using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I ended up using function call, so I get flexibility to change color at 1 place instead of changing expression in all the coloumns (if business decides to change color). And my code is as below

```
Public Function RankColour(ByVal Value As Integer, ByVal MinValue As Integer, ByVal MaxValue As Integer) As String
Dim strColor As String

Select Case Value
    Case MaxValue
        strColor = "Salmon"
    Case MinValue
        strColor = "LightGreen"
    Case Else
        strColor = "White"
End Select
Return strColor
  End Function
```

And then expression used in column cell as below:

```
=Code.RankColour(me.value, Min(Fields!AbsenteeismRank.Value, "dataset1"), Max(Fields!AbsenteeismRank.Value, "dataset1"))
```

Comment: For information if you need to perform multiple updates as an rdl file is effectively XML you can open it in a text editor and do a simple find and replace to update the colors in all the expressions

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from a single expression within your text box.

Set the `BackgroundColour` of your textbox to be

```
=iif(Fields!myRank.Value = min(Fields!myRank.Value, "DataSet3"),
    "Green",
    iif(Fields!myRank.Value = max(Fields!myRank.Value, "DataSet3"),
        "Red",
        "White"
    )
 )
```

Will give the result

[image]

This is because you are searching the current value of `myRank` against the maximum and minimum values of `myRank` within the entirety of your dataset `DataSet3`.

Please let me know if this solves your problem, or if you require further assistance.

Comment: Thanks it works, my only concern is performance since I need to do conditional formatting for 40+ attributes, but will let you know how I go

Comment: Another option is to set the value of the colour in the data source.  If for example a SQL query or view examine the value of 'myRank' and return a string value which is the colour name, call the column BGColour.  Assign the string value to the background colour attribute for the cell in the tablix.

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple expression at the '**Font / FontWeight**' property in order to switch to **Bold** all non-zero values:

```
=iif(Fields!ingresos.Value > 0, "Bold", "Default" )
```

It works!